# Executing Combine Publishers in parallel creates race condition

Tags: swift, combine, healthkit

I'm trying to query HealthKit for heart rate values and steps in the time interval defined by a [`HKWorkoutEvent`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkworkoutevent#) to fill a custom local model I have defined to store multiple variables, it's defined below.

```swift
struct SGWorkoutEvent: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let type: HKWorkoutEventType
    let splitActiveDurationQuantity: HKQuantity?
    let splitDistanceQuantity: HKQuantity?
    let totalDistanceQuantity: HKQuantity?
    let splitMeasuringSystem: HKUnit

    let steps: HKQuantity?
    let heartRate: HKQuantity?
}
```

Al properties except `steps` and `heartRate` can be extracted from a `HKWorkoutEvent`. However, I am trying to build a Combine pipeline that would let me create an array of publishers to query in parallel for heart rate, steps and also pass the workout event so in the `sink` I receive a 3-element tuple with these values so I can populate the model above. What I  currently have is below,

```swift
// Extract the workout's segments (defined automatically by an Apple Watch)
let workoutSegments = (workout.workoutEvents ?? []).filter({ $0.type == .segment })

// For each of the workout segments defined above create a HKStatisticQuery that starts on the interval's
// beginning and ends on the interval's end so the HealthKit query is properly defined to be
// executed between that interval.
let segmentsWorkoutPublisher = Publishers.MergeMany(workoutSegments.map({ $0.dateInterval }).map({
    healthStore.statistic(for: HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.heartRate)!, with: .discreteAverage, from: $0.start, to: $0.end)
}))
.assertNoFailure()

// Do the same logic as above in `segmentsWorkoutPublisher` but for steps
let stepsPublisher = Publishers.MergeMany(workoutSegments.map({ $0.dateInterval }).map({

    healthStore.statistic(for: HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.stepCount)!, with: .cumulativeSum, from: $0.start, to: $0.end)
}))
.assertNoFailure()

Publishers.Zip3(workoutSegments.publisher, stepsPublisher, segmentsWorkoutPublisher)
    
    .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
    .sink(receiveValue: { pace, steps, hrs in
        
        let d = SGWorkoutEvent(type: pace.type,
                               splitActiveDurationQuantity: pace.splitDuration,
                               splitDistanceQuantity: pace.splitDistance,
                               totalDistanceQuantity: pace.totalDistanceQuantity,
                               splitMeasuringSystem: pace.splitMeasuringSystem,
                               steps: steps.sumQuantity(),
                               heartRate: hrs.averageQuantity())
        
        self.paces.append(d)
    })
    .store(in: &bag)
```

`HKHealthStore.statistic(for:...)` is nothing but a Combine wrapper for `HKStatisticsQuery` defined on a `HKHealthStore` extension, see below.

```swift
public func statistic(for type: HKQuantityType, with options: HKStatisticsOptions, from startDate: Date, to endDate: Date, _ limit: Int = HKObjectQueryNoLimit) -> AnyPublisher<HKStatistics, Error> {
    
    let subject = PassthroughSubject<HKStatistics, Error>()
    
    let predicate = HKStatisticsQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: startDate, end: endDate, options: [.strictEndDate, .strictStartDate])
    
    let query = HKStatisticsQuery(quantityType: type, quantitySamplePredicate: predicate, options: options, completionHandler: { (query, statistics, error) in
        
        guard error == nil else {
            hkCombineLogger.error("Error fetching statistics \(error!.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }
        
        subject.send(statistics!)
        subject.send(completion: .finished)
    })
    
    self.execute(query)
    
    return subject.eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

What I am seeing here is some sort of race condition where both steps and heart rate retrieved is not returning ad the same time. As a result I see values that don't make sense like on one 1K split of 5' 200steps and another one of the same duration 700steps. The real case should be that those two intervals should show a value around 150 but it seems that I am probably not using the correct Combine operator.

The expected behavior I would hope to see is for every publisher on `Publishers.Zip` to have each 3-item tuple have finished its query in order (1st interval, 2nd interval...) rather than this non-replicable race condition.

To try and give more context I think this is akin to having a model with temperature, humidity and chance of rain for different timestamps and querying three different API endpoints to retrieve the three different values and merge them in the model.

Comment: It's hard to help when your code doesn't compile. I would suggest making a sample project that has similar functionality and posting that. That said, at first glance, your `statistic` method is doing way too much. Trim that down to 3-4 arguments and refactor. Also, `Array` has a publisher. Rather than using MergeMany try `workoutSegments.publisher` and play around with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lot to unpack here, but I'll give it a shot.  Let's start with your `HKHealthStore.statistic` function. You want to run an (presumably asynchronous) query, publish a sequence with a single result, that then ends. This really seems like an ideal case to use a `Future`. I don't have any experience (at all) with `HealthKit` and I can't guarantee this will compile, but a transformation **might** look something like this:

```
public func statistic(
    for type: HKQuantityType,
    with options: HKStatisticsOptions,
    from startDate: Date,
    to endDate: Date,
    _ limit: Int = HKObjectQueryNoLimit) -> AnyPublisher<HKStatistics, Error> {

    let future = Future<HKStatistics, Error> {
        fulfillPromise in

        let predicate = HKStatisticsQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: startDate, end: endDate, options: [.strictEndDate, .strictStartDate])

        let query = HKStatisticsQuery(quantityType: type, quantitySamplePredicate: predicate, options: options, completionHandler: { (query, statistics, error) in
            guard error == nil else {
                hkCombineLogger.error("Error fetching statistics \(error!.localizedDescription)")
                fulfillPromise(.failure(error!))
            }

            fulfillPromise(.success(statistics!))
        })

        self.execute(query)
    }

    return future.eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

So now we have a "one shot" publisher that runs a query and fires when it has a value.

Now let's look at your `segmentsWorkoutPublisher` (and by extension `stepsPublisher`).

In working with Combine, you should be VERY wary if you find yourself using the `Publisher.<SomeOperatorType>` constructors. In my experience it's rarely right thing to do.  (Having said that, using `Zip3` later seems OK to me).

In this case you are creating a sequence of `Publishers` (your `Futures`).  But you're really not interested in a sequence of `Publishers`.  You're interested in a sequence of the *values* those `Publishers` produce. In a sense you want to "unwrap" each Publisher (by waiting for its value) and send those results down the sequence. This is exactly what `flatMap` is for! Let's do something like this:

```
let segmentsWorkoutPublisher =
    workoutSegments
        .map { $0.dateInterval }
        .flatMap {
            healthStore.statistic(for: HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.heartRate)!, with: .discreteAverage, from: $0.start, to: $0.end)
        }
        .assertNoFailure()
```

This generates a string of sequences, but then waits for each one to emit a value and sends the values farther along.

And `stepsPublisher` would change in a similar way.

I think that will get you where you need to go.  As part of looking at this, created a Playground where I reworked your example but with more simplified types.  Next time you run into a problem like this you might try something similar - filter away the superfluous details and try to create a simpler example.  If you can put your code together like this in a playground, that will compile without too much trouble, it will make it easier to answer questions.  The Playground:

```
import Foundation
import Combine
import PlaygroundSupport

enum MockEventType : CaseIterable {
    case segment
    case notSegment
}

struct MockSegment {
    let type : MockEventType
    let dateInterval : DateInterval = DateInterval.init(start: Date.now, duration: 3600)
}

func statistic() -> AnyPublisher<Float, Never> {
    let future = Future<Float, Never>() {
        fulfillPromise in

        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            sleep(UInt32.random(in: 1...3))
            fulfillPromise(.success(Float.random(in: 100.0...150.0)))
        }
    }

    return future
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}

// Generate an endless stream of mock events.
let rawWorkouts = Timer.publish(every: 1.0, on: .current, in: .common)
    .autoconnect()
    .map{ _ in MockSegment(type: MockEventType.allCases.randomElement()!) }

let workoutSegments = rawWorkouts.filter { $0.type == .segment }

let dateIntervals =
    workoutSegments
        .map { $0.dateInterval }

let segmentsWorkoutPublisher =
        dateIntervals
        .flatMap { _ in statistic() }
        .assertNoFailure()

let stepsPublisher =
        dateIntervals
        .flatMap { _ in statistic() }
        .assertNoFailure()

var bag = Set<AnyCancellable>()

Publishers.Zip3(workoutSegments, stepsPublisher, segmentsWorkoutPublisher)
    .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
    .sink(receiveValue: { pace, steps, hrs in
        print("pace: \(pace) steps: \(steps), hrs: \(hrs)")
    })
    .store(in: &bag)

PlaygroundSupport.PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```